# Python decorator for a subfunction

Tags: python, decorator

I am designing a `PyQt` window in which `FileOpenDialog` is called. Once the return value is obtained from `FileOpenDialog`, `loadItem()` will load the image. I want to log this event and append it to log, which is a QListWidget. I want to achieve this using a decorator for enhanced reusability and cleanliness of code.

I have created a class decorator called `logAction`, which will append a string to the `QListWidget` based on the function and *args.

```
class logAction:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function=function
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if(function.__name__ == "promptOpen"):
            self.logOpen()

    def logOpen(*args, **kwargs):
        import re
        extensionPattern = re.compile(r"""
        ^(.+?)
        ([^\\]+)$
        """, re.VERBOSE)
        file = extensionPattern.search(args[0])

        self.log.addItem(f"Loaded {file}")


def promptOpen(self):
    self.openDialog = FileOpenDialog(self)

    @logAction
    def loadItem(path):
        pass

    loadItem(self.openDialog.filePath)
```

> NameError: name 'logAction' is not defined

The error is at @logAction. How do I allow the `loadItem()` to be decorated by `logAction`, while putting not the class within the `promptOpen()`?

Comment: @BobWhite you CAN use a decorator inside a function. And any other place, there is really no restrictions to that

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Please see the first comment and create a minimal example that anyone can copy/paste and use, and still get your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class test2:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func=func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if(self.func.__name__ == "mama"):
            self.logOpen()
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def logOpen(self):
        print('well done')


def hi():

    @test2
    def mama():
        print('here')

    mama()

hi()
```

Result: well done
        here

you wrote `if(function.__name__ == "loadItem"):` without self as `self.function.__name__` and the name of the function was wrong it doesn't point to the right function name

I just tried to make a reproduce of your code by my way works well.

you code will be nice if you add `if(self.function.__name__ == "loadItem")`

```
class logAction:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function=function
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if(self.function.__name__ == "loadItem"):
            self.logOpen()

    def logOpen(*args, **kwargs):
        import re
        extensionPattern = re.compile(r"""
        ^(.+?)
        ([^\\]+)$
        """, re.VERBOSE)
        file = extensionPattern.search(args[0])

        self.log.addItem(f"Loaded {file}")


def promptOpen(self):
    self.openDialog = FileOpenDialog(self)

    @logAction
    def loadItem(path):
        pass

    loadItem(self.openDialog.filePath)
```